# CSS Bootstrap input text transparent with bottom border only (Chrome)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap, how do I make input text transparent and have bottom border only? I have tried the following:

```
#login input[type=text] {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

the background of the input text is still white, what am I doing wrong? This issues only appears in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an id to the input field the `input[type=text]` is not relevant because there will be only one field with that id

so try this:

```
 #login {
border: 0;
outline: 0;
background: transparent;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the border:0 will work, because at the bottom your border-bottom overwrites.  A stronger expression would be giving border-top, border-right and border-left 'separately' a zero value, while defining the border-bottom its value.